# php curl login on website with different accounts

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I've made a php script to login to a website. The script works fine but the problem is that I sometimes have to login on the same website with differents accounts. If I post the second login, the first session still exist and the site redirect me to the login page. If I post the second login again, it works fine.

So my question is how I can kill the previous session with the second login.

EDIT 1: I run the scripts with my browser. After the login it redirects to the website it self. If I close the browser between 2 login posts, it works fine. So the script have to kill the previous session in the browser itself.

Thank you in advance.

my code:

```
function post_data($url, $data, $header){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath("cookie.txt"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath("cookie.txt"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    return curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    unset($ch);
}
```

Comment: Just create a new curl handle.

Comment: Like I said in my edit: I run the scripts in my browser. After the login it redirects to the website it self. The website sets session cookies in my browser. If I close my browser this cookies will be deleted, but I like to do this programmaticly instead of restart my browser every time I run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different cookiejar? You could add a 4th argument to add custom curl options to overwrite default options:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php